# How to only display a square section of the video feed from expo-barcode-scanner?

Tags: react-native, expo, barcode-scanner

I need to use a barcode scanner for my react native expo project, but I only want to display a square section of the camera feed to it will nicely fit in a popup (Modal). So far, it has only display the camera aspect ratio. I haven't found anything on how to do that with expo-barcode-scanner.

Is there a way I can do this?